# What type of music is this ,Mexican-Romantic track "Manny and Meche" from Grim Fandango?

Tags: identify-this-genre

Of what "type" is [this](https://youtu.be/q41xhqgTryM) Mexican-Romantic music track?

The track is "Manny and Meche" from the 1998 video game [Grim Fandango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grim_Fandango).

Thanks,

Comment: That's a good soundtrack.I wonder if it's a genre all its own. Like "video game soundtrack latin jazz" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a beautiful example of the Argentine tango, a type of music invented for the Argentine version of the famously intimate [dance of the same name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqOEVM4kkJk).  To be exact, it is an example of "nuevo tango" style created by the Argentine composer [Astor Piazzolla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astor_Piazzolla)'s influential fusion of the distinctive  3+3+2/8 *tresillo* tango rhythm with elements of jazz and classical music. Compare the following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgha2OTkyFE

You might get closest to your example with some combination of these terms:  "slow acoustic guitar argentine tango ballad."  There are some particularly [nice variations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGbRZ73NvlY&list=PLrr_iRnxvCpm3v4_QWOIKtwWzwzwVbYfy) on this style by the Buena Vista Social Club.